# Understanding spaCy stock entity types and their application

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I need to annotate a corpus of international relations/policy articles, for which I use spaCy (with Prodigy atop). The default English models come with a set of pre-defined entity types, most of which are, in theory, easily applicable to my purposes. However, the only piece of documentation I found is just a table with very short descriptions, which does not answer the (quite numerous) questions I faced while working on the annotation.

So my *primary* question is: aren't there bigger accurate guides/documentation on all these entity types (e.g. NORP, GPE and so on), or at least an extensive set of examples? I simply fear that I might've been searching incorrectly all of this time.

I also suspect that the generalized guides might be considered rather dull by some, cause they would not address many very individual cases, but I also think that having them might make basics for the newcomers (like me) a lot easier.

And in case such documentation is nowhere to be found, I would appreciate if someone could help at least with the most important questions (I consider them too small to open separate topics for all of them, but I also might be wrong):

1. Is NORP only meant for tagging names of national/ethnic groups, or is it also used when an adjective indicates that another entity belongs to some nation/group. So in 'Iranian nuclear program', it is ok to tag 'Iranian' as NORP?
2. In case where the name of something is followed by an abbreviation, e.g. 'Non-proliferation treaty (NPT)', should it be considered one or two separate entities? What could define my choice?
3. Similarly, when one phrase implies two entities, but they are not 100% separated syntactically, how can I capture both entities correctly? Say, with the following example, which indicates two separate events:

> "concluding documents of the Madrid and Vienna conferences"

4. There are certain cases of ambiguity, e.g. 'Kyoto' may refer to the protocols just as well as to the town:

> (...) undermines most points of the Kyoto.

'Protocols' part is simply omitted, cause it is pretty obvious for most readers that protocols are implied. However, is there a sure way to disambiguate 'Kyoto' as LAW (which I presume is an appropriate label here) and 'Kyoto' as GPE (city)?

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Honnibal kindly [answered my questions on Prodigy support forum](https://support.prodi.gy/t/understanding-stock-entity-types-and-their-application/1860), so below I am just retelling/quoting his words (and suggest to read his answers in that thread):

1. As for NORP - my assumption was correct, so in 'Iranian Nuclear Program' it'd be correct to tag 'Iranian' as NORP, because

> The adjectival forms are capitalised in English, and so we compromise and call them "entities", even though they really aren't.

2. If both name and acronym appear next to each other, they should be treated as separate entities. E.g. [see this](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent?text=International%20Business%20Machines%20(IBM)%0A%0A&model=en_core_web_lg&ents=person%2Corg%2Cgpe%2Cloc%2Cproduct%2Cnorp%2Cdate%2Cper%2Cmisc)
3. Neither Kyoto nor conferences problem have a simple solution to them. As far as I understand, the easiest way round would be just to exclude similar occurences from the training data. But if absolutely necessary, there might be a partial answer to the conferences problem with dependency parsing (though I don't know what the exact implementation would be like).